# Trouble converting addresses to lat/long with Google Geocoding API.

Tags: java, geocoding

I have an application that will read an Excel spreadsheet that contains a large list of names and addresses (800+), convert the address to lat/long using the Google Geocoding API, and generate a .kml document with associated waypoints.

When converting a large amount of addresses the .kml file will end up with small groups that have been assigned the same lat/long for different addresses.  I am wondering if I need to process small batches, pause the program, and process another batch?

```
public void GeocodingSample() throws IOException, XPathExpressionException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException
{

    l1 = new String[lineCount];
    l2 = new String[lineCount];
    //address2 = add;
    //city2 = city;

    bxg.UpdateTA("Converting address to lat/long...");

    ProgressBar progress = new ProgressBar();


    // URL prefix to the geocoder
    String GEOCODER_REQUEST_PREFIX_FOR_XML = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml";

    // query address
    address = new String[lineCount];

    int x = 0;

    //System.out.println("Im about to enter the loop and the count is: "+lineCount);

    while(x < lineCount)
    {
        pbarvalue = x + 1;

        address[x] = (sheet[x][a2]+", "+sheet[x][s2]);

        progress.PbarValue(pbarvalue, lineCount, address[x]);

        url = new URL(GEOCODER_REQUEST_PREFIX_FOR_XML + "?address=" + URLEncoder.encode(address[x], "UTF-8") + "&sensor=false");

        // prepare a URL to the geocoder
        //URL url = new URL(GEOCODER_REQUEST_PREFIX_FOR_XML + "?address=" + URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8") + "&sensor=false");

        // prepare an HTTP connection to the geocoder
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        Document geocoderResultDocument = null;
        try 
        {
          // open the connection and get results as InputSource.
          conn.connect();
          InputSource geocoderResultInputSource = new InputSource(conn.getInputStream());

          // read result and parse into XML Document
          geocoderResultDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(geocoderResultInputSource);
        } finally {
          conn.disconnect();
        }

        // prepare XPath
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        // extract the result
        NodeList resultNodeList = null;

        // a) obtain the formatted_address field for every result
        resultNodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address", geocoderResultDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for(int i=0; i<resultNodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
          //System.out.println(resultNodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
        }

        // b) extract the locality for the first result
        resultNodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/GeocodeResponse/result[1]/address_component[type/text()='locality']/long_name", geocoderResultDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for(int i=0; i<resultNodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
          //System.out.println(resultNodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
        }

        // c) extract the coordinates of the first result
        resultNodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/GeocodeResponse/result[1]/geometry/location/*", geocoderResultDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for(int i=0; i<resultNodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
          Node node = resultNodeList.item(i);
          if("lat".equals(node.getNodeName())) lat = Float.parseFloat(node.getTextContent());
          if("lng".equals(node.getNodeName())) lng = Float.parseFloat(node.getTextContent());
        }
        //System.out.println("lat/lng=" + lat + "," + lng);
        l1[x] = (""+lat);
        l2[x] = (""+lng);

        // c) extract the coordinates of the first result
        resultNodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/GeocodeResponse/result[1]/address_component[type/text() = 'administrative_area_level_1']/country[short_name/text() = 'US']/*", geocoderResultDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for(int i=0; i<resultNodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
          Node node = resultNodeList.item(i);
          if("lat".equals(node.getNodeName())) lat = Float.parseFloat(node.getTextContent());
          if("lng".equals(node.getNodeName())) lng = Float.parseFloat(node.getTextContent());
        }
        //System.out.println("lat/lng=" + lat + "," + lng);

        x++;
    }//end While

    //System.out.println("The output is ready");

    progress.ShowFrame(false);
    OutputKML();



}// end GeoCoding Sample
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your use of the Google Maps API is forbidden by the terms of service:

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

> No Mass Downloads or Bulk Feeds of Content: (...) For example, you are not permitted to offer a batch geocoding service that uses Content contained in the Maps API(s).

Also:

> (g) No Use of Content without a Google Map. You must not use or display the Content without a corresponding Google map

Some alternatives you have:

http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open

http://services.gisgraphy.com/public/geocoding.html

About your specific geocoding problem, do results change in time? If it's not the case, maybe there is a parsing error - or simply addresses could not be located precisely ending on the same coordinates.
On the other hand, putting a delay after each request may help.